# how to auto refresh multiple php variables without refreshing page? I can only do one atm

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to auto-refresh multiple PHP variables. So far I can only auto-refresh one variable and the rest do not work (it will always be the last one that works, so `var2`).

I was thinking of making a JSON script and trying to do it like that but how would I go about making each array in the JSON to auto-refresh on my PHP page without refreshing the whole page?

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.timer-1.0.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<?php $ra = "<div id='c1b'></div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#c1b').load('var1.php');
        refresh();    
    });
    function refresh(){
        setTimeout( function() {
            $('#c1b').fadeOut('slow').load('var1.php').fadeIn('slow');
            refresh();  
        }, 2000);
    }
    </script>";
$rb = "<div id='c2b'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#c2b').load('var2.php');
            refresh();    
        });
        function refresh(){
            setTimeout( function() {
                $('#c2b').fadeOut('slow').load('var2.php').fadeIn('slow');
                refresh();  
            }, 2000);
        }
        </script>"; ?>

<?php echo $ra . ' & ' . $rb ?>
```

var1.php

```
<?php 
include_once 'connect.php';
$d= 'var1';
$q = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM var WHERE name = ?");
$q->bindParam(1, $d);
$q->execute();
while($r = $q->fetch()){
    $e = $r['names'];   
}
echo $e;
?>
```

var2.php

```
<?php 
include_once 'connect.php';
$d= 'var2';
$q = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM var WHERE name = ?");
$q->bindParam(1, $d);
$q->execute();
while($r = $q->fetch()){
    $e = $r['names'];   
}
echo $e;
?>
```

Comment: It's not possible to refresh only some variables without "refreshing" the page. `PHP` is stateless, it generates whole page with single query. I think you're looking for [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: yes i believe it it is AJAX but the script i have above works.. but it just refreshes one variable which is $var2 but when i remove var2, $var1 will start to work.. so this tells me that it works but just one variable can be refreshed at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can read this, you're going to have two functions named "refresh" defined on your page.

Try changing the script in your second one to a unique name, e.g.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#c2b').load('var2.php');
        refreshvar2();    
    });
    function refreshvar2(){
        setTimeout( function() {
            $('#c2b').fadeOut('slow').load('var2.php').fadeIn('slow');
            refreshvar2();  
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: YOUR A STAR Thanks.. It was killing me for days.. Works i honestly should have known.